# Send info from last INSERT on Database to a php file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery function on a panel as part of an ERP, making an INSERT via a PHP file. The INSERT is correctly made, as the database always receives info properly, but I am unable to send that last inserted record back in order to show it on screen on real time.

jQuery function (seems to be working properly)

```
function showSuggestions (datos) {
$('tbody *').empty();
var resultados= datos;
$('tbody').on('keydown').html(resultados);}
```

Content on the PHP file making the insert (**INSERT works properly**):

```
        $nombreTurno = $_POST['tu_name'];

        $insertar = mysql_query("INSERT INTO turn_conf (tu_id,tu_name,tu_status) VALUES ('','$nombreTurno','1')");
        $lastInsert=mysql_insert_id();
        $select =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM turn_conf WHERE tu_id='$lastInsert'");

        $data="";
                    $name=$select['tu_name'];
                    $turn_id=$select['tu_id'];
                    $data= '<tr>
                        <td><span class="tableContentRow">'.$name.'</span></td>
                        <td class="editColumn"><a href="#"><div class="editIcon"></div></a></td>
                        <td class="discontinueColumn"><a href="/Gestion/config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php?id='.$turn_id.'"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a></td>
                        </tr>';      echo $data;
```

What is coming back to the panel is the HTML piece, but with no values on `'.$name.'` and `'.$turn_id.'` so the row is added, but empty. There's no console error, and I've checked that `$lastInsert` contains the correct info: this INSERT's id that has just been done.

EDIT_ I've also tryed by `$turn_id=$lastInsert;` with no result.

Comment: hmm... wouldn't inserting `''` into the `tu_id` column make it... `''`?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but please know that the mysql_* functions have been deprecated. Please start using [mysqli](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: what is that html data tells you

Comment: @ferozakbar it is explained on last paragraph: the HTML piece, but with no values on '.$name.' and '.$turn_id.' so the row is added, but empty.

Comment: @KevinB, if you mean to give the value to $tu_id like this: **$turn_id=$lastInsert;** I have just done and it still bring me the variables empty... Thank you.

Comment: @ferozakbar: <tr>
<td><span class="tableContentRow"></span></td>
<td class="editColumn"><a href="#"><div class="editIcon"></div></a></td>
<td class="discontinueColumn"><a href="/Gestion/config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php?id=84"><div class="discontinueIcon"></div></a></td>
</tr>

Comment: @Biomehanika i meant in your insert statement. You're inserting `''` into the `tu_id` column... If that's an autonumber column, shouldn't you just leave that column out of the insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you've missed this

```
$result= mysql_fetch_array($select);
print $result['tu_name'];
print $result['tu_id'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the reason. I'll tick in 2 minutes. Very grateful feroz.

Comment: i didn't undrstnd y did u said xactly 2 mins :?

Comment: Check is available 5 minutes after the answer has been posted. Thanks!